# PHP if statement disabling a button

Tags: php

I am trying to disable a button when a specific file doesn't exist, by adding "disabled" to the markup via a php if/else. But I end up with a blank page with no errors or anything... Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  <?php if(file_exists('uploads/'.$results->id.'_.jpg')){ 
    echo ''; 
  }else{ 
    echo 'disabled'; } 
  ?>
>
```

If I wrap the whole button in the same if statement and just hide it, it works just fine, but I want to disable it as opposed to hiding it. Anything jump out as wrong there?

Comment: What does `var_dump( file_exists('uploads/'.$results->id.'_.jpg') );` returns ?

Comment: you shouldn't mix php with html

Comment: @Dwza `shouldn't mix php with html` really? What is the workaround here?

Comment: @KamranAhmed yes. he should try templatesystems like [SMARTY](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: @KamranAhmed or he could easy use ajax (or jquery) to exchange data

Answer (score 1):

if i would mix html with php, **what i would actually never do**, then i would tye this source like:

```
<?php 
    $status = "";
    if(!file_exists( 'uploads/' . $results->id . '_.jpg' )){ 
        $status = "disabled";
?>

<button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    <?php echo $status; ?>
    >
```

but i think for you is better to use ajax or jquery to exchange data

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Stuff</button>

<?php if(file_exists('uploads/'.$results->id.'_.jpg')) : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
        </script>

<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  <?php echo (file_exists('uploads/'.$results->id.'_.jpg'))?'':'disabled'; ?> />
```

use this :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
  <?php 
  if(file_exists('uploads/'.$results->id.'_.jpg')){ 
    echo 'Enabled'; 
  }else{ 
    echo 'Disabled'; 
  } 
  ?>
  </button>
```

This will label your button

Comment: Actually this results a button with the label Enable or Disable